# Using an InputStream for random access

Tags: java, httprequest, inputstream, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a project where I want to download separate byte arrays from one big file.

At the moment, every time I do this I create a `new HttpRequest` and use the `setHeader()` method for the Range.

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url.toString());
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
request.setHeader("Range", "bytes=0-1024");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
response.setHeader("Content-Range", "bytes 10-20/1024");
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();`
```

Ideally, I would:

1. Start streaming from the 10th byte
2. Read 10 bytes.
3. Get from byte an integer n
4. Read n bytes somewhere in the middle of the 1024 byte file

all without creating a new `HttpRequest` every time.

Because this content-range doesn't work like I expect it to work, the `InputStream` always starts at the beginning of the file.

Also, `inputstream.skip()` will not work for this because I do not want to download all of the bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you code your request so that you will receive a 'chunked' response - ie a stream that you can filter with "interrupt/discard" saving every nth block?

Details:

Code your header so you get chunked respose

Use POST instead of GET to force the "100 continue " header in response if needed. Probably dont need so you can default to a GET.

```
 http-outgoing-1 >> "POST /cre_mpg.php HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
 http-outgoing-1 >> "Content-Length: 309[\r][\n]"
 http-outgoing-1 >> "Host: 192.168.1.143[\r][\n]"
 http-outgoing-1 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
 http-outgoing-1 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
 http-outgoing-1 >> "Expect: 100-continue[\r][\n]"
 http-outgoing-1 >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
 http-outgoing-1 >> "[\r][\n]"
```

the response:

```
 http-outgoing-1 << "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue[\r][\n]"
 http-outgoing-1 << "[\r][\n]"
 http-outgoing-1 << HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
 http-outgoing-1 >> "infil1=http%3A%2F1.jpg&infil2=http%3A%36.flac&otfil=2036.mp4&t=3.00"
 http-outgoing-1 << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
 http-outgoing-1 << "Server: nginx/1.6.0[\r][\n]"
 http-outgoing-1 << "Date: Fri, 09 May 2014 00:51:43 GMT[\r][\n]"
 http-outgoing-1 << "Content-Type: text/html[\r][\n]"
 http-outgoing-1 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
 http-outgoing-1 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
 http-outgoing-1 << "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.11-3+deb.sury.org~precise+1[\r][\n]"
 http-outgoing-1 << "[\r][\n]"
 http-outgoing-1 << "c1[\r][\n]"
```

NOTE: neither req nor response contains header="Content-length:"

in your stream filter, the first data block has lenth=c1 so read it and keep
then in your filter , just alternate blocks, consuming to /dev/null blocks that you dont want. The conn will stay open and will keep streaming. Your filter just needs to be able to interpret what's on the Wire and available to read in the streamed-response.

Block headers and protocol details available in the RFC.

using 'curl --trace-ascii'  you can display the blocks in the chunked response.